# Sort Featured Content by Order instead of ID

Tags: sort

I am generating a Featured Content with the following code:

```
<?php
$featured_posts = get_featured_posts();
foreach ( (array) $featured_posts as $order => $post ) :
    setup_postdata( $post );
    get_template_part( 'content', 'featured-post' );
endforeach;
?>
```

The page looks like this, sorted by ID:

```
<article id="post-201">...</article>
<article id="post-204">...</article>
<article id="post-227">...</article>
<article id="post-331">...</article>
<article id="post-530">...</article>
<article id="post-633">...</article>
<article id="post-759">...</article>
```

I need to sort by Page Order instead. Is this code OK for this purpose?. This works OK.

```
usort($featured_posts, function($a, $b) {
    return $a->menu_order - $b->menu_order;
});
```

Comment: What's that `get_featured_posts()` function? Never seen it before and can't find it in the WordPress documentation anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `get_featured_posts()` returns an array of `WP_Post` objects, then yes, the `usort()` function you have should work properly.

If you have access to `get_featured_posts()`, and it uses `get_posts()` or a `WP_Query` instance, then you can set the `orderby` parameter to `menu_order`, and drop the `usort()` call.